# Oracle - Trim and Leading 0

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi guys – I need your help with the below line of code. Currently working on Oracle database.

```
THEN TRIM(substr((TO_CHAR(TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM s.sales_number))),6))
```

The above line of code will strip leading zeros and get the last 9 digits of the sales number but somehow is not working for some records, below is an example of the data

```
Data                expected 
0057889123995683    123995683 this is okay, it is what I expected
0000000300043467    for this I get 3467 but I expect to see is this 800043467
```

How can I modify the code so it works as expected?

Many Thanks.

Comment: what if after removing the leading zeros, the number of digits is less than 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `substr()` properly for getting the last 9th digits. Instead, you must pass `-9` as an argument to `substr()`. You are getting the correct result with `0057889123995683` only because it only has two trailing zeros.

After a little bit playing with your code, this worked for me:

```
select TRIM(substr((TO_CHAR(TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM '0000000300043467'))),-9)) from dual
```

Change your code to:

```
THEN TRIM(substr((TO_CHAR(TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM s.sales_number))),-9))
```

However, this approach won't work if after removing the leading zeros, the number of digits is less than 9. To solve this, first remove the leading zeros and then invoke `substr()` if the length is greater 9 (using an `IF` statement) :

```
trimmed := TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM s.sales_number);

IF LENGTH(trimmed) > 9 THEN
 trimmed := substr(trimmed,-9);
END IF;
```

As @Ben indicated, `TRIM()` implicitly converts to a character, there's no need to convert to a character afterwards.

Comment: However, this approach won't work if after removing the leading zeros, the number of digits is less than 9. To solve this, first remove the leading zeros and then invoke substr if the length is > 9 (using an `IF` statement)

Comment: `TRIM()` implicitly converts to a character, there's no need to convert to a character afterwards (plus by enclosing in double quotes it's already a string literal). Not sure why you would trim a second time at the end either?

Comment: @Ben thank you. I edited the answer. I'm also not sure why OP trims a second time at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Please try executing this.

```
THEN TRIM(substr((TO_CHAR(TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM s.sales_number))),0))
```

It worked for me.